# No overload for method 'WeightOut' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, syntax

No overload for method 'WeightOut' takes 2 arguments

My code was working before I tweaked it to make it more efficient.

this is the working code:

In the BASE class I have:

```
public virtual double WeightOut(double weightOut, double wightIn)
        {
            return Math.Round((weightOut = (weightIn + 0.12)), 2);
        }
```

Then in the INHERITED class I have:

```
public override double WeightOut(double weightOut, double weightIn)
        {
            return Math.Round((this.WeightIn() + 0.12), 2);
        }
```

Then I changed it so that I am not using the same code in both classes and rather only in the inherited class as so:

In the BASE class:

```
public abstract double WeightOut();
```

In the INHERITED class:

```
public override double WeightOut()
        {
            return Math.Round((this.WeightIn() + 0.12), 2);
        }
```

I then got the syntax error when compiling with this line of code that leads from the WeightOut() method in the same INHERTIED class:

```
public override double HowMuchTheFishWeighOutKG()
        {
            return this.FishPerTank() * this.WeightOut(0, 0) * this.Tanks();
        }
```

so I then changed it to:

```
public override double HowMuchTheFishWeighOutKG()
        {
            return this.FishPerTank() * this.WeightOut() * this.Tanks();
        }
```

The syntax error still stands:

No overload for method 'WeightOut' takes 2 arguments.

**(ANOTHER SMALLER PROBLEM)
It tells me where the error is: 37,59
but Visual Studio does not show me where that is, and I will have to count myself to find where it is.**

Comment: it's not clear what error you get **finally**. What erro is it?

Comment: somewhere in your code you are calling WeightOut with 2 arguments.

Comment: You will be disappointed to find `return Math.Round((weightOut = (weightIn + 0.12)), 2)` isn't going to return a value out to your calling method. Check out the `out` keyword.

Comment: Have you tried "Clean Solution" from the build menu? If visual studio is giving you a location it cannot find by itself, it sometimes helps.

Comment: The code: return Math.Round((weightOut = (weightIn + 0.12)), 2) works perfectly fine and I have tested it. That isnt the problem. The problem is that as Jason says, somewhere in my code I am calling WeightOut with 2 arguements apparently, even though I have gone through my code as you can see from what I posted and I have changed it all to not call two arguments... but I still receive that error.

Comment: I have now tried Clean Solution, with no success to the syntax error I received before!

Comment: @cameron my comment is unreleated to the issue you are asking about. I'm just pointing out that assigning a new value to a valuetype parameter is not going to reflect that change outside the method. So if you're trying to pass the unrounded value out of the method via the parameter, I encourage you to test it again.

Comment: Okay roken, I see what you are saying, and thank you, although it is only the rounded number that I care about. But for future reference I shall take your advice.

Comment: @cameron The solution to your "smaller problem" is apparently that the status bar is hidden. To re-enable, go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General and "Show Status Bar". At least in my version.

Comment: If you noted which version of VS you are using, I didn't catch it. I have found the VS 2008 sometime holds on to error messages after the error has been corrected, but rebuilding (or clean solution, as suggested) generally fixes it. Some other version might behave differently. I'd try manually deleting all the files generated by the build process, then re-building completely.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using methods, rather than properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I would check:
In the base class, are you certain that the abstract method for WeightOut has NO parameters.  The complaint being issued could have something to do with a mis-match from the inherited function definition.

Second thing to check, Right Click on the Inherited Classes "WeightOut" function (the function name specifically) and select the option `Find All References`.  This should give you a list of every place in the code, by class name/filename and line number, that calls this function.  That might help.

Note: if you dont have that option, please elaborate which version of Visual Studio you are using?

Also Note: this can be done with a "Find in Files" search as well for the function name.  This search will return more false positives, but will still locate all references to the function.

Also, even in vs 2005, if you double click the error in the Errors box, it should put your cursor on the line that is causing an issue, or rather the line that is throwing the error, if its not a code line but instead is like a closing `}`, then that tells us something different.